# Sudo git pull origin master as apache in EC2

Tags: php, git, amazon-ec2, ssh, sudo

I'm trying to create webhook for autoupdate my repository trough EC2 instance with `php exec()` script. The valid ssh key for all git commands is owned by sudoers.

So I need to run this after each commit:

```
exec('
cd ~/var/www/html/site/repo-test &&
sudo git pull origin master &&
sudo chown -R apache:apache ~/var/www/html/site/repo-test');
```

It is not working at all, I think it's because of the webhook file is ran by apache:apache. But I didn't setup any password for sudoers, so why the apache admin can't execute sudo?

Comment: Why not just inspect the output and see what the problem is?

Comment: yes I did, the problem is the apache admin can't do sudo even the sudo doesn't have any password, then what should I do so the apache can run sudo command?

Comment: `man 5 sudoers`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%5Bsudo%5D+without+password https://serverfault.com/search?q=%5Bsudo%5D+without+password https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsudo%5D+without+password